# Cannot export Robot class

Tags: java, awtrobot

I have an application and have some problem and hopefully I can get some help.
The application is rather simple and is taking care with login and two-way authentication at my stock provider using the [AWT] `Robot` class.
I am running Windows10 and Eclipse. Google Chrome is the application it is running against, i.e. I am using <kbd>ctrl + T</kbd> to open a new tab.
The problem I have is that application running as expected when running from Eclipse, but when doing an export as a runnable file
the application is not working, the `keyPressed` is not working, only the mouse.
A quick Google search tells that I should use `KeyListener` instead but I do not know how and if it is really that problem.

main class

```
package login;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import robothelper.RobotHelper;

public class Login 
{;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable 
{
    new Login();
}

public Login() throws Throwable
{
    doLogin();
}   

private void doLogin() throws InterruptedException, Throwable 
{
    Robot robot = new Robot();  
    
    robot.setAutoDelay(40);
    robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
    Thread.sleep(25000);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
    RobotHelper.type(KeyEvent.VK_T, robot);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
    RobotHelper.type("url)", robot); 
    RobotHelper.type(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,robot);
    Thread.sleep(12000); //page to load
    RobotHelper.setMousepointerLocation(robot, 335, 1100);
    RobotHelper.leftClick(robot);
    RobotHelper.type("user", robot);
    RobotHelper.type(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, robot);
    RobotHelper.type("pass", robot);
    RobotHelper.type(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,robot);
    RobotHelper.setMousepointerLocation(robot, 53 , 950);
    RobotHelper.leftClick(robot);
    Thread.sleep(1000); //addon to open
    runAvanzaAddon(robot);
    RobotHelper.setMousepointerLocation(robot, 335, 1100);
    RobotHelper.leftClick(robot);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    RobotHelper.type(KeyEvent.VK_V, robot);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    RobotHelper.type(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, robot);
    RobotHelper.type(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,robot);      
}

private void runAvanzaAddon(Robot robot) throws HeadlessException, 
UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException, InterruptedException
{
    RobotHelper.setMousepointerLocation(robot, 150, 740);
    RobotHelper.leftClick(robot);;      
    String nowValue = getValuFromClipboard(); 
    String prevValue = getValuFromClipboard();

    while(nowValue.equals(prevValue))
    {
        Thread.sleep(200); 
        prevValue = nowValue; 
        RobotHelper.setMousepointerLocation(robot, 150, 740);
        RobotHelper.leftClick(robot);
        nowValue = getValuFromClipboard();
    }       
}

private String getValuFromClipboard() throws HeadlessException, 
UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
{
        return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
    .getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor
    .stringFlavor); 
 }
}
```

help class

```
package robothelper;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class RobotHelper 
{

public static void leftClick(Robot robot) 
{
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); 
}

public static void type(int i, Robot robot) 
{
    robot.delay(40);
    robot.keyPress(i);
    robot.keyRelease(i);
}

public static void type(String text, Robot robot) 
{
    StringSelection stringSelection = new 
    StringSelection(text);
    Clipboard clipboard = 
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}

public static void setMousepointerLocation( Robot robot, int 
x,int y)
{
    robot.mouseMove(y, x);
}

public static Point getMousepointerLocation()
{
    return MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is shorter example everyone can run.
Application opens a new tab in chrome (ctrl T).
I guess the issue is because of `Keylistener`. I got it to work once.
Steps to reproduce:

1. run application from Eclipse on top of Chrome (a new tab will be opened).
2. export and run application on top of Chrome (a new tab will NOT be opened).

```java
package login;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import robothelper.RobotHelper;

public class Login 
{;    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable 
    {
        new Login();
    }
    
    public Login() throws Throwable
    {
        doLogin();
    }   

    private void doLogin() throws InterruptedException, 
    Throwable 
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();  
        
        robot.setAutoDelay(40);
        robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        RobotHelper.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T, robot);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
    }
}
```